# GLKMathProject returns {NaN, y, z}

Tags: ios, glkit

This question also posted on Apple Dev forum but I'm getting no answers there, so hopefully someone here will catch whatever it is I'm doing wrong here!

I'm relatively new to OpenGLES and GLKit, and I'm trying to get the screen co-ords of an object I've draw at {x, y, z} in the object space. I've written a small convenience method:

```
-(GLKVector3)projectX:(float)x Y:(float)y Z:(float)z zRot:(float)rot scale:(float)s
{
    GLKVector3 retVal;
    CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;
    GLKVector3 object = GLKVector3Make(x, y, z);
    int viewPort[4];
    viewPort[0] = 0;
    viewPort[1] = 0;
    viewPort[2] = (int)viewSize.width;
    viewPort[3] = (int)viewSize.height;
    float aspect = fabsf(viewPort[2] / viewPort[3]);
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65), aspect, 0.1f, 100);
    GLKMatrix4 baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    // _rotation is an iVar that takes the device angle into consideration.
    baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(baseModelViewMatrix, _rotation, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0f);
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(x, y, z);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, rot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(modelViewMatrix, s, s, 1.0);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);
    
    retVal = GLKMathProject(object, modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix, &viewPort[0]);
    return retVal;
}
```

I then call it as I draw the object:

```
GLKVector3 t = [self projectX:myObject.x Y:myObject.y Z:myObject.z zRot:myObject.angle scale:1.0]; //typically myObject.angle=0.0
debugUITextView.text = NSStringFromGLKVector3(t);
```

But all I get is something along the lines of "{NaN, 100.23367, 0.99888}" - the actual values of Y and Z vary - X is always NaN.
 
I've tried removing the lines that scale and rotate the matricies as well as plugging direct numbers in such as

```
GLKVector3 object = GLKVector3Make(0.5, 1, 0);
```

But always the same result. The y and z values seem correct; as I drag the object down/up the screen the y decreases/increases.
 
Could someone tell me if there's a magic trick to using GLKMathProject, please!?
 
Thanks,
 
Todd.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem occurs because of my line:

```
float aspect = fabsf(viewPort[2] / viewPort[3]);
```

It turns out I wasn't casting my variables far enough, it should read:

```
float aspect = fabsf((float)viewPort[2] / (float)viewPort[3]);
```

and then I get expected results.

Clearly it's my gap in compiler knowledge: I assumed that the variables would be implicitly cast...!